# Android Nearby Connections

Tags: google-nearby

I'm developing an app using Nearby Connections. Is there a way to make a device keep on discovering when the app is out of focus and no longer in the foreground? This is possible with devices running Android version code <= M, but not >= Q.

Comment: Does your app have BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission granted? Note that you must request fine location first, and then request separately for background location after fine is granted. And note that this isn't necessary on Android T+

Comment: It doesn't, because BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission has not been granted by Google. Anyway, why does Nearby Connetions API needs location permissions? It is supposed to work with a combination of Bluetooth, BLE, and Wifi hotspots. So, in principle, no location is involved in the process.

Comment: Before Android T, Bluetooth and WiFi APIs required fine location permissions because they can indirectly leak the user's location (eg. "Family Room TV" means the user is probably home. Or if you drive around in a van and collect SSIDs, you can match the IDs you found to what you've collected.) After Android T, these were put into their own dangerous permission group.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear and detailed explanation. Finally, I understood why Nearby Connetions API requires location permissions. What I need for my app is a way to automatically connect users having the same app installed, even if the app is not running (using a background service for example). Any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: Doing anything in the background isn't going to be easy. There are power/privacy concerns. Is it not possible to have the app open on at least one of the sides?